# Oracle Listener (how to add an XE SID)?

Tags: oracle, listener, sid

I am brand new to Oracle and the instruction is to "Add an XE SID. Select the first entry and copy it." (the following is the given code) do I just copy and paste in the editor?

## listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\PC\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora

## Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =

(SID_LIST =

(SID_DESC =

(SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)

(ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\PC\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)

(PROGRAM = extproc)

(ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\PC\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")

)

)

LISTENER =

(DESCRIPTION_LIST =

(DESCRIPTION =

(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.14)(PORT = 1521))

(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))

)

)